# MySQL - Select max revision within nested statement

Tags: mysql

I would like to select max revision drawings from mysql table.
I can't use anything but nested select statement(?) (all conditions should be after 'SELECT * FROM `drawings`').

So, the 'drawings' table is:

```
+----+---------+-------------+-------+---------+---------------------+
| id | number  | title       |format | revision| date                |
+----+---------+-------------+-------+---------+---------------------+
| 100|  022588 |  some title | dwg   | 1       | 2016-01-07 08:00:00 |
| 101|  022588 |  some title | dwg   | 2       | 2016-01-07 08:01:00 |
| 103|  022588 |  some title | pdf   | 3       | 2016-01-07 08:15:32 |
| 104|  022588 |  some title | dwg   | 3       | 2016-01-07 09:10:32 |
+----+---------+-------------+-------+---------+---------------------+
```

Result I would like to get is (same number, largest revision for appropriate format):

```
| 103|  022588 |  some title | pdf   | 3       | 2016-01-07 08:15:32 |
| 104|  022588 |  some title | dwg   | 3       | 2016-01-07 09:10:32 |
```

And once more, I have (must) to start query with 'SELECT * FROM `drawings` WHERE ......'.

Last thing I tried were:

```
SELECT * FROM `drawings` WHERE `revision` IN ( SELECT MAX(`revision`) FROM `drawings` GROUP BY `number`, `format` ) GROUP BY `number`, `format` ORDER BY `number` DESC;
```

... and I got an proper pdf and wrong/lowest dwg (1 instead of 3).

Comment: Just curious, is 'title' the same as 'filename'

Comment: @Strawberry. No sir, I have another column with a link containing filename (some columns were removed from the sample). And title, drawing title, could be whatever, e.g. 'Construction Site layout' or 'Emergency cooling system' etc.

Comment: So that's manually entered by the user?

Comment: @Strawberry: Not by user. Initially by designer, drawing creator, on Contractor's side (often in Excel). Later it's copied from csv transmittal to the Owner's db. Can't imagine users entering a dozen thousands titles. What the mess it would be :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the query:

```
select *
from drawings a inner join (select number, title, format, 
                            max(revision) as revision
                            from drawings 
                            group by number, title, format) b 
on a.number = b.number and a.title = b.title and a.format = b.format
and a.revision = b.revision
```

Comment: that doesn't work. Will return duplicate drawings because not all are at the same revision.

Comment: don't edit your question to steal another person's solution. That's disgraceful.

Comment: What? Be careful with your words... If it is the same as other one have answered, just disconsider... I may be late, but does not means that I do not find this answer through testing it.

Comment: ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'b.revision' in 'on clause'

Comment: This should fix it.

Comment: Thank you! (someone decide that i should use at least 15 chars to say 'thank you')  :-)

Comment: It's really do the job, however I forgot a 'where statement'. Any hint how could I install your solution after the unchangeable part (select * from drawings where ...[something I can't avoid]....AND [your solution])

Answer (score 2):

If I read your question correctly, then you want to get drawings from each `format` group having the maximum revision number in that group.  One approach uses a subquery to identify formats and their max revisions, and then uses that subquery to restrict the original `drawings` table.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM drawings t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT format, MAX(revision) AS revision
    FROM drawings
    GROUP BY format
) t2
    ON t1.format = t2.format AND
       t1.revision = t2.revision
```

**Follow the link below for a running demo:**

## SQLFiddle

Comment: And once more, I have (must) to start query with 'SELECT * FROM drawings...

Comment: @beba This is beginning to sound like a homework assignment.

Comment: :-D   It's faster to copy/paste from the question than to comment every !answer. 'Dear Tim Biegeleisen, thank you very much for your prompt answer. You are all guys fast as electricity. Thank you all. Unfortunately I must preserve SELECT * FROM drawings'.

Comment: If anyone recognize my above comment as irony, it's definitely not true.
I'm really grateful to Tim Biegeleisen and all of you helped me to resolve my problem.
Any (if exist) misunderstanding could be only because of my "perfecto" english :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a corelated subquery in the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT d1.*
FROM `drawings` d1
WHERE `revision` = (
    SELECT MAX(`revision`)
    FROM `drawings` d2
    WHERE d2.`number` = d1.`number`
      AND d2.`format` = d1.`format`
) 
ORDER BY `number` DESC;
```

[See it on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/99975/5/0)

The query will return exactly one row for each combination of `number` and `format` with the highest revision. I use that combination because of your original query: `GROUP BY number, format`. But you also wrote: "largest revision for appropriate format". In this case you should use:

```
SELECT d1.*
FROM `drawings` d1
WHERE `revision` = (
    SELECT MAX(`revision`)
    FROM `drawings` d2
    WHERE d2.`format` = d1.`format`
) 
ORDER BY `number` DESC;
```

Comment: @Ven - would you please explain, what you do mean?

Comment: My query will return exactly one row for each combination of `number` and `format` with the highest revision! Here's Tims fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/99975/2

Comment: I'm wrong. Sorry! Adding a sqlfiddle link to your answer (so I can upvote it instead)

Comment: And once more, I have (must) to start query with 'SELECT * FROM drawings...

Comment: @beba - You can replace `SELECT d1.*` with `SELECT *` [it works fine](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/99975/6) because there is no other table involved in the FROM clause.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest:

select d1.* from drawings d1
where d1.id in (
   select max(d2.id) from drawings d2 group by d2.format
)

Querys using PrimaryKey are faster. And you get the last record revision.

Comment: And once more, I have (must) to start query with 'SELECT * FROM drawings...