# Mysql - combine two queries, 1st is unchangeable

Tags: mysql

I need to join two mysql queries.

1st is unchangeable, I can't avoid it:

```
select * from `drawings` where `issued` > '2015-08-01';
```

2nd is to select only latest revisions for appropriate drawing number and file format:

```
select *
from drawings a inner join (select number, title, format, 
                            max(revision) as revision
                            from drawings 
                            group by number, title, format) b 
on a.number = b.number and a.title = b.title and a.format = b.format
and a.revision = b.revision;
```

Any hint how i could combine it?

The point is that I can't change anything in the 1st part. It should remain unchanged, as above...

Any solution should start AFTER unchanged 1st part.

BTW, the `drawings` table:

```
+----+---------+-------------+-------+---------+---------------------+
| id | number  | title       |format | revision| date                |
+----+---------+-------------+-------+---------+---------------------+
| 100|  022588 |  some title | dwg   | 1       | 2016-01-07 08:00:00 |
| 101|  022588 |  some title | dwg   | 2       | 2016-01-07 08:01:00 |
| 103|  022588 |  some title | pdf   | 3       | 2016-01-07 08:15:32 |
| 104|  022588 |  some title | dwg   | 3       | 2016-01-07 09:10:32 |
+----+---------+-------------+-------+---------+---------------------+
```

**Clarification:**
After the 1st part I could enter whatever I want in order to get latest revisions for both dwg and pdf entries, for the appropriate drawing number.

Comment: What do you mean by unchangeable? It's bad practice to use wildcards in production code and one way to combine the results of the two queries would be to use `union` or `union all`, but that would require both queries to select the same columns, which they don't, because of the wildcards.

Comment: @Brian. I mean that I can't change beginning of query. My task is to add a 2nd part to existing query in order to get only latest revisions of dwg and pdf entries for each drawing number. I suppose that you are 100% right regarding to 'bad practice', however, chocolate fattening but I eat it every day. Such is live :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my modified answer from your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39334436/5563083):

```
select * from `drawings` where `issued` > '2015-08-01'

AND `revision` = (
    SELECT MAX(`revision`)
    FROM `drawings` d2
    WHERE d2.`number` = drawings.`number`
      AND d2.`title`  = drawings.`title`
      AND d2.`format` = drawings.`format`
) 
ORDER BY `number` DESC;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cebebc/1

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.*  
  FROM drawings a 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT number
            , title
            , format
            , MAX(revision) revision
         FROM drawings 
        GROUP 
           BY number
            , title
            , format
     ) b
    ON b.number = a.number 
   AND b.title = a.title 
   AND b.format = a.format 
   AND b.revision = a.revision
 WHERE a.issued > '2015-08-01';
```

Comment: You must use "SELECT *  FROM drawings ..." ;-) - see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39334436/mysql-select-max-revision-within-nested-statement).

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I don't understand that rule, so I'm ignoring it. Such is life.

Comment: That might be some strange ORM. Or kind of query template like "SELECT * FROM tablename {%inject_your_code_here%}". However - bebe should clarify that to not confuse us.

Comment: It's kind of query template like "SELECT * FROM tablename {%inject_your_code_here%}"

Comment: @beba Except it's not. If it was, then there wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Strawberry: Whatever it is, thank you very much for your time and your help. I got working query. And to satisfy your curiosity: both table and query were significantly reduced for this question purpose. I'm not allowed to change anything in existing system (company rules, policy). My task were to create extension to query that would be added if necessary on the fly to existing/working query.